# Error while using jpackage: exited with 263 code

Tags: java, jpackage

When i try to run jpackage to create a .exe file to my jar of java project it returns a error:

```
java.io.IOException: Command [light.exe, -nologo, -spdb, -ext, WixUtilExtension, -out, C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage16947518480288913921\images\win-exe.image\sistemaEstoque-1.0.msi, -sice:ICE27, -loc, C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage16947518480288913921\config\MsiInstallerStrings_en.wxl, -cultures:en-us, C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage16947518480288913921\wixobj\main.wixobj, C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage16947518480288913921\wixobj\bundle.wixobj, C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage16947518480288913921\wixobj\ui.wixobj] in C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage16947518480288913921\images\win-msi.image\sistemaEstoque exited with 263 code
```

This is the command i'm trying to run:

```
jpackage -t exe --name sistemaEstoque --description "JAVA project" --app-version 1.0 --input C:\Users\Vinicius\Downloads --dest C:\Users\Vinicius\Downloads --icon Hopstarter-Button-Button-Next.ico --main-jar teste.jar --win-console --win-shortcut --win-menu
```

Do you guys have any idea of what is causing the error?

Note: i'm not using an javaFX application

I didn't found anything related to extied 263 code

Comment: Does light.exe exist on your system?

Comment: @VGR yeah this is the path to it C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin

Comment: What you can do to diagnose is to run the jpackage command with `--temp temp` to create a stable temporary directory, and if it fails again, run the command from the exception message.

Comment: Note also that for `--input`: "All files in the input directory will be packaged into the application image." which might not be what you want, and might be whats tripping up the `light` command.